# Using Database In Custom Annotation Validator Effectively in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, annotations

So I want to update user data, but before it, I want to check if the user data exist in my database using membeId given from the request.

Usually, I'll find the user data first using 'findByMemberId' function provided by spring and check the result. If the result is null, I should throw some errors because it means the user is not in the database. And if it exists I'll continue the update process.

Now I want to try using a custom annotation validator from spring to check whether the membeId exists or not. Here is my ConstraintValidator class

```
@Component
public class MemberIdMustExistsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MemberIdMustExists, String> {

  @Autowired
  private MemberRepository memberRepository;


  @Override
  public void initialize(MemberIdMustExists memberIdMustExists) {
    
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
      return true;
    }

    return memberRepository.findByMemberId(value) != null;
  }
}
```

I attached the annotation in memberId field and here is my service class :

```
@Service
public class UpdateMemberImpl implements UpdateMember {
  
  @Autowired
  private MemberRepository memberRepository;

  @Override
  public Single<GetMemberResponse> execute(
      GetMemberRequest request) {
    Member memeber = memberRepository.findByMemberId(request.getMemberId());

    //logic to update goes here
  }
}
```

It looks simpler because I don't have to check whether the user exists or not and throw some errors in the service class. But I noticed that I call the database more than if use the first way to update user data. With this method, I need to call 'findByMemberId' twice, the first is for checking the existence in CustomValidator class and the second is to get the user data in the service class to update the data.

Is there a more effective way for this case or Did I do it wrong? Because I want to use Custom Annotation Validator but it seems like requires me to make a call to the database more than I use the normal way.